# Assert the tested class internal objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, easymock, software-quality

I am using Easy mock.

1. I call a method of my actual class from my Test class.
2. Inside that method I create an object called 'A' on the fly with child objects.
3. I pass that object 'A' to a remote service and a output returns.

I don't want to asset that returned output. (That is already taken care of)

I want assert and make sure that, my object created successfully and weather it contains the relevant child objects?
Can I access this object from my Test Class before or after it get passed to remote service.

Is this possible.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Mock the remote service, and use a [capture](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#capture-org.easymock.Capture-) when mocking the remote call. The get the actual value passed as argument from the capture, and check that it contains everything expected.

Something like the following (not tested):

```
Capture<A> capture = EasyMock.newCapture();
expect(mockRemoteService.someMethod(capture)).andReturn(whatever);
...

A a = capture.getValue();
// now check that a is OK.
```